# How to preserve (or add) a space between a text node and an element?

Tags: html, css

I have to highlight a given word in a string. To highlight a word I wrap it in a span element and give that span a special class. For that I wrote the following code:

```
const splittedLine = text.split(wordToHighlight);

// some other code    

<div class="wrapper">
  {splittedLine[0]}
    
  <span class="highlighted">
    {wordToHighlight}
  </span>
    
  {splittedLine[1]}
</div>
```

And this works as expected. If I want to highlight a word "player" I would get such result:

> a new **player** has connected

But the thing is I don't need the *wrapper* div. And when I try to get rid of this div,it ruins the result.
If I just omit the wrapper div then whitespaces between the span element and text nodes are removed. Even if strings in splittedLine[0] or [1] have leading/trailing spaces those spaces are ignored and I get the following string:

> a new**player**has connected

I also tried to use `display: contents` with the wrapper div. But I get the same result as without a wrapper div at all.

I tried to add spaces explicitly with `{" "}` but they are also ignored.

How do I preserve whitespaces around the span element when I remove the wrapper div? And why does div even matter in this case?

P.S. I use Svelte framework. And the string with highlighted word should be a result a certain component returns. The reason why I need to get rid of the wrapper div is that this component is already wrapped in some div. I just don't want the result string to be wrapped twice.

Comment: Can you share enough of your (relevant), "*[mcve]*" code to allow us to recreate your problem, and help provide an answer? Without that, we're just throwing suggestions and guesses into the void with no assurance that it's at all helpful, productive, or even approximately correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this:

1. Use a `<pre>` instead of a div, this will preserve the whitespace between the elements but probably not desirable if you're trying to get rid of the div anyways
2. Use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces when padding out the splittedLine variables, these shouldn't get ignored
3. Set `white-space: pre;` in the CSS of the container, this will make it act like a `<pre>`

Comment: I used the 3rd option and it works like magic. Thanks you!